# MEAN stack app shows 404 in console when requests for data

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

In a basic complaints based db app, (CRUD) built on MEAN stack, I'm having issues while routing and Mongo returns 404 on console when I request for data based on hostel name.

https://github.com/ajayns/hostel-complaint-portal/tree/db-hostel-fix
This is the branch which I'm working that which has the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaG24.png)

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code and found that you missed express listen code, because of this you were getting 404 error
[image: output Screen]

And you can follow my github [link](https://github.com/hamidabdul1994/hostel-complaint-portal), Here i made changes

Comment: Hey! Actually the issue wasn't with the page loading by itself. After saving objects in the MongoDB, the app doesn't seem retrieve them in the list page (one after login page)